# Sed to remove the line with exact pattern

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am trying to find the exact match of the pattern `$i` in `C1.txt` file and the remove the matching lines using sed command. But ended up with issue. Please find my findings and other details below.

**C1.txt**

```
# file: /home/mytest/data # owner: own # group: group-sm user::r-x group::rwx mask::rwx other::--- default:user::rwx default:group::r-x default:group:smr:rwx default:group:agm:r-x default:mask::rwx default:other::---
# file: /home/mytest/datasr123 # owner: own # group: group-sm user::r-x group::rwx mask::rwx other::---
```

**Variable value**

```
i=/home/mytest/data
```

**Code**

```
#!/bin/bash
Input=C1.txt
  j=0
      while IFS= read -r line;
      do
      j=$((j+1))
        Exists=$(echo $line | grep -iwoP "$i" )
        if [[ ! -z "$Exists" ]]; then
        sed -i "$j /\b"$i"\b/d" "$Input"
        fi
      done <"$Input"
```

**Expected Result**

`C1.txt`

```
# file: /home/mytest/datasr123 # owner: own # group: group-sm user::r-x group::rwx mask::rwx other::---
```

**Error Message**

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unknown command: `/'
```

Comment: I need to remove only the line which matches the exact pattern ```/home/mytest/data``` from the file ```C1.txt```. Hope now it clarifies.

Comment: *Both* lines of your input match that pattern.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get an error is because your search string contains `/` characters, which are confused with the marker characters. In other words, you are asking `sed` to do this:

```
sed "//home/mytest/datasr123/d"
```

which produces the error you saw. IOW, the pattern cannot contain the character that you use as a marker. If you know that your pattern does *not* contain a given character, you can use that character as a marker; e.g. since there is no `;` in your search string, you could do this:

```
sed "\;/home/mytest/datasr123;d"
```

orr in terms of `$i`:

```
sed "\;$i;d"
```

See the man page of `sed` under `Addresses` for details on how to specify addresses.

Of course, whether this is useful depends on whether you know of a character that will never occur in your search strings: any character will do as a marker, but if your search string is input by the user, there are no guarantees that what you choose will not occur in the search string - you would have to scan it in order to find a character that does not occur in it.

And the easiest method is to *not* use `sed` at all, but fall back on grep (with thanks to @Kusalananda for fixing my bone-headed mistakes):

```
grep -v -F -e "$i" -- <file>
```

will show only the lines that do not match the pattern (that's the `-v` - the `-F` tells grep to interpret the string literally, not as a regexp, so that for example `*` and `.` are matched literally; the `-e` allows the pattern to start with a `-` and not be interpreted as an option to `grep`; and the `--` allows the *filename* to start with a `-` and not be interpreted as an option to `grep`; the last two are *always* good to have in a `grep` invocation inside a script, since you never know when that situation may arise, although we mostly get away with it when `grep` is called interactively).

BUT N.B.:
The question has been edited and the change in the pattern has invalidated *every* method in this answer completely. The pattern matches *both* lines in the input, so both of them will be deleted. You would have to reinterpret the pattern somehow, e.g. look not for `"$i"` since this will match both; instead look for `"${i} "` where the additional space will match the first line but not the second, or `"${i}s"` to match the second line but not the first. Note also that with `-F`, you cannot use character classes (so `\b` is out).

Answer (score 0):

The original `grep -iwoP`does not seem to reflect the idea of an "exact match".... however

To delete complete lines exactly matching the search string then it needs anchoring at the beginning `^` and end `$` of the line.

```
sed "\|^$i$|d" C1.txt
```